# Calculating homology groups of a mapping cone

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have the following question:

Let $X$ be the mapping cone of a map $f:S^1\longrightarrow S^1$ of degree $k.$

1. Compute the groups $H_n(X).$
2. Compute the groups $H_n(\bar{X}),$ where $\bar{X}$ is the universal cover of $X.$

I was able to solve the first part of the question by considering a CW-complex of $X$ with one 0-cell, one 1-cell, and one 2-cell. I got $H_0(X) = Z,$ $H_1(X) = Z_k$ and $H_n(X) = 0$ otherwise. Could someone please help me with part 2?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez
I think the universal covering is a CW complex with k 0-cells, k 1-cells, and k 2-cells. I looked at the case k=2 to get some idea and it doesn't help solve the problem. In this particular case, $X=RP^2$ with 2 from each 0,1,and 2-cells, and the universal covering is $S^2.$

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez
The case k=3 is confusing me :( For the case k=2, I think $H_0(\bar{X})=Z$ (since it is path connected) and $H_1(\bar{X})=0$ (since it is simply connected).

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez
Working on it now. Thank you for helping. I'm not very good at this.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez So the Euler characteristic is 2. So that means that the $H_2$ is free of rank 2? Could you please elaborate on this as to why?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez
Thank you. I'll work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X$ is simply the $2$-disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|\le1\}$ quotiented by $z\sim \zeta_kz$ for $z\in S^1=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$.

I claim $\overline X$ is $k$ copies of the $2$-disk $D_1\sqcup\cdots\sqcup D_k$, with all the $\partial D_i=S^1$ glued to each other (a sort of lasagna): $z_i\sim z_j$ for $z\in S^1$, where $z_i\in D_i$ and $z_j\in D_j$. It is easy to see that $\overline X$ is simply-connected, and there is a degree $k$ covering $\overline X\to X$ given by $z_i\in D_i\mapsto \zeta_k^iz_i\in D$. Thus $\overline X$ is the universal cover of $X$.

Now $\overline X$ is a CW complex with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell, and $k$ two-cells, and one can compute $H_i(\overline X)$ by cellular homology.

Comment: Thank you! I have a small question. I don't understand how the gluing works here in this 'Lasagna'-like object. Are the boundaries of disks identified to a single point as in a wedge?

Comment: no, they are identified into a single circle. Perhaps it looks more like a ravioli.

Comment: I am having difficulty picturing this in my head and hence it's difficult for me to do the calculation. But thank you for your answer. I will work on this.